# Perl - Net::DNS to create PTR record

Tags: perl, dns

First, the relevant xkcd comic: http://xkcd.com/979/

Next, the 10-year old thread on PerlMonks: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=210422

Basically, I'm failing in my attempts to use Net::DNS::Update to create a PTR record and I'd like to see how others have manged this.

Below is what I'm trying. $hst is the hostname that I already have an A record for. $rev is the backwards IP address in-addr.arpa thingy.

```
# Create the update packet:
my $update = Net::DNS::Update->new($OURDOMAIN);

#  Add the PTR record:
$update->push(update => rr_add("$rev 3600 PTR $hst"));

# Send the update to the zone's primary master.
my $res = Net::DNS::Resolver->new;
$res->nameservers("$OURNMSERV");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `$OURDOMAIN` is your main domain name, you need to know that you can't put PTR records into your own domain, they have to be put in the right `.in-addr.arpa` zone.

That zone is most likely being run by your ISP, and they're unlikely to support dynamic updates from end users.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I did try Net::DNS::Update->new("in-addr.arpa"), as per the suggestion in the 10-year old PerlMonks thread, but had no luck. I would not think these PTR records would be managed by our company's ISP; this is all internal DNS.

Comment: so you've got an internal zone set up for the IP address space you're using?  e.g. if you're using `192.168.1/24` you'd need a zone `1.168.192.in-addr.arpa` on your nameserver.

Comment: Resolved.  Do a 'dig -x' on a valid IP address on the network.  The "AUTHORITY SECTION" shows the in-addr.arpa zone to use for the 'new Net::DNS::Update' parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Another ten years later, http://xkcd.com/979/ is still relevant. Having read the question and answer and also the linked PerlMonks thread, it was still unclear to me how to properly add PTR records using `Net::DNS`.

Well, 'when in Rome do as the Romans do' the saying goes. Having noticed that `nsupdate` can add PTR records to our internal DNS system just fine without me specifying the reverse zone, I was trying to find out what it does to send valid updates. Turned out it actually sends a SOA query first to figure out what the reverse zone is. Copying this behavior seems to be a somewhat robust way to add PTR records via `Net::DNS`:

```
use Net::DNS;

my $hostname = 'somehost.example.com.';
my $ip = '10.11.12.13';
my $primary_ns = 'primary.example.com';

# First, construct the reverse name based on the IP address
my @octets = split /\./, $ip;
my @rev_octs = reverse(@octets);
my $rev_name = join(".", @rev_octs) . '.in-addr.arpa.';

# Then, query the SOA record for the constructed reverse name
my $resolver = Net::DNS::Resolver->new();
$resolver->nameservers($primary_ns);
# Note: Need to use 'send' rather than 'query' since we are interested
# in the 'authority section' of the reply only.
my $packet = $resolver->send($rev_name, 'SOA');

my $zone;
if ($packet) {
    # We expect only one authority record
    my $len = $packet->authority;
    if ($len == 0) {
        # Server might not be authorative for reverse lookup zone.
        warn "No authority section in reply.\n";
        exit 1;
    }
    my $auth = ($packet->authority)[0];
    $zone = $auth->name;
} else {
    warn 'query failed: ', $resolver->errorstring, "\n";
   exit 1;
}

# Armed with this information, we can finally add the PTR records
my $update = Net::DNS::Update->new($zone);
# Make sure that the PTR record does not already exist
$update->push( pre => nxrrset("$rev_name PTR") );
$update->push( update => rr_add("$rev_name 1200 PTR $hostname") );

my $reply = $resolver->send($update);
if ($reply) {
    if ($reply->header->rcode eq 'NOERROR') {
        print "Successfully added PTR record!\n";
    } else {
        print 'Update failed: ', $reply->header->rcode, "\n";
    }
} else {
    print 'Update failed: ', $resolver->errorstring, "\n";
}
```